# Prisma 2: Unknown arg `where` in select.count.where for type undefined

Tags: prisma, prisma2

I'm unable to apply a where clause to a simple count() query on a model. If I remove the where clause it works just fine and returns the number of rows in that table.

Good:
`let result = await prisma.articles.count()`

Bad:
`let result = await prisma.articles.count({ where: { article_id: 1 } })`

Error:

```
Unknown arg `where` in select.count.where for type undefined. Did you mean `select`? Available args:
type count {

}
```

It doesn't matter which column in the schema I use, same error. How do I troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The above syntax is correct. Could you confirm if your `@prisma/cli` and `@prisma/client` are on the same version. If so, could you run `npx prisma generate` and check again. I am currently on version `2.2.0` and it works for me.

Also as a last resort, reload your editor to check the updated types so that count can be detected.

Comment: Bingo - the versions were slightly off. Thanks!